# convert an arraylist to two dimentional array and also change format a bit

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have an arraylist containing many records like

```
"2013-7-13 \n 12 hour(s) 23 minute(s)"
 "2013-7-14 \n 4 hour(s) 19 minute(s).
```

How can i covert this two dimentional array, `string[][],` making it looks like

```
{"2013-7-13", "12h23m"}, {"2013-7-14", "4h19m"}.
```

I need this two dimentional array so that i can draw a barchart in XY and display in android device. X represents the date, while Y represent the time.

Comment: What have you tried ? Because the trivial way would work. Should we have to write it for you ? (hints : use String.split and String.match methods)

Comment: You should convert the strings to some kind of DateTime objects (preferably JodaTime or JSR310, but otherwise java.util.Date) as early as possible, and pass those around instead.

Comment: my problem is not using "split()", but how to convert to two dim array, i have no idea how to make this loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.split to split each string into parts.

```
// untested, not even for compilation errors
String[][] twoDimArray = new String[oldArr.length][];
for (int i = 0, n = oldArr.length; i < n; i++) {
    String splitMe = oldArr[i];
    twoDimArray[i] = splitMe.split("\n");
}
```